# Python ApacheSpark load data directly from AWS S3

Tags: apache-spark

I have a public link to AWS S3 which basically provides a text file. If I go directly to the S3 url, it automatically downloads the text file to my computer. 
I want to use ApacheSpark to directly load the text file as a data frame without staging the data in databrick. I've tried using sparkContext as well as the addFile and getFile option available but no luck.

How can this be done? Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

in databricks you can download files to your cluster, in a cell just do the following...

`%sh curl -O www.my-s3-bucket.com/file/name.txt`

except with the url of your data :)

if you really want to get the data in spark it's recommended that you mount the s3 bucket to your databricks filesystem, but you can use the `s3a` protocol as well. see [this page](https://docs.databricks.com/spark/latest/data-sources/aws/amazon-s3.html) for more details

Comment: Thanks for your assistance. However, the requirement clearly stated that the data should be read directly from S3 and should not be staged in databrick. My understanding is that I should be able to load the data directly into a data frame using the S3 public url. The url doesn't require a access key and secret.

Comment: I get this error: Unable to load AWS credentials from any provider in the chain when I do spark.sparkContext.textFile('s3://bucket/file.txt'). The problem is that I don't need credentials to access the file. It's accessible via just using the url: https://s3.amazon.com/bucket/file.txt

Comment: you need to tell the S3A connector to use the "AnonymousCredentialProvider", which is a configuration option covered in the Hadoop documentation.

Comment: Thanks for you help but I still get the same error as before. I am trying to use the addFile() and Sparkfiles method as my alternative but I am getting InputPath does not exist. I am new to Apache Spark and finds it a bit confusing in its documentation.